# Detecting if item is checked inside of getView() in a adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

When a listView row is pressed,  I do this : `listView.setItemChecked(position, value)`.  This changes the background color with a `selector` to show the position is active.

I also do basic zebra stripes in my `adapter`'s `getView()` method.  Like this:

```
if (pos % 2 == 1) {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#99DEEAF1"));
} else if (viewType != 0) {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
}
```

Now in this `getView()` method, I'd like to know if my item (in the current `position`) is checked so that I don't try to change the background color (as seen above) and override my selector for my `listView`.  Is this possible?

In the end I want to add a clause to the `if` statement that don't do either one if item is checked.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a helper class like this to remember the selected postion:

```
public class ListChoice
{
    private int selection;

    public void setListChoice(int s)
    {
        selection = s;
    }

    public int getListChoice()
    {
        return selection;
    }
}
```

then:

```
listView.setItemChecked(position, value);
ListChoice lc = new ListChoice();
lc.setListChoice(position);
```

and in getView()

```
if(pos != lc.getListChoice())
{
    if (pos % 2 == 1) 
    {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#99DEEAF1"));
    } 
    else if (viewType != 0) 
    {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Model class which take care wether a list item is checked or not inside `getView()` method.

```
OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            //Update the model here
        }
    };
```

For help go through this [link](http://amitandroid.blogspot.com/2013/03/android-listview-with-checkbox-and.html)